# why won't Postal Rate code work

Tags: python, string

I need Help the Error I get is that the cost is not defined. This Program Calculates Postal rates based on type of shipping and weight. I am not exactly sure what i am doing wrong some advice would be very thankful

```
def main() :
    '''The program calculates the cost of postal rates through the type of
    shipping and the weight of the package'''

Shipping = int(input("Shipping: Enter (1) stamps or (2) for meter postage: "))
Size = int(input("Package size: Enter (1) for standard size or (2) for 
oversize: "))
Weight = int(input("What is the weight in grams of the envelope?: "))

#Standard shipping
if Shipping == "1" :
        if Size == "1" :
            if weight <= 30 :
                cost = "1.00"
            elif weight  >=31 <=50 :
                cost = "1.20"
if Shipping == "2" :
        if Size == "1" :
            if weight <= 30 :
                cost = "0.77"
            elif weight  >=31 <=50 :
                cost = "1.18"
#Oversize shipping
if Shipping == "1" :
        if Size == "2" :
            if weight <= 100 :
                cost = "1.80"
            elif weight  >101 <=200 :
                cost = "2.95"
            elif weight  >=201 <=300 :
                cost = "4.10"
            elif weight  >=301 <=400 :
                cost = "4.70"
            elif weight  >=401 <=500 :
                cost = "5.05"

if Shipping == "2" :
        if Size == "2" :
            if weight <= 100 :
                cost = "1.65"
            elif weight  >101 <=200 :
                cost = "2.68"
            elif weight  >=201 <=300 :
                cost = "3.76"
            elif weight  >=301 <=400 :
                cost = "4.27"
            elif weight  >=401 <=500 :
                cost = "4.58"



   #Print the answer

print("This shipment will cost you ${0:.2f}".format(cost)) 

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You convert 'Shipping' and Size to an integer type with `int(...)` but you compare it as a string type `"1"`.

It never matches, so cost is never set to anything.

When you print the answer, you can't, because cost was never set to anything.

To fix it, keep Shipping as a string:

```
Shipping = input("Shipping: Enter (1) stamps or (2) for meter postage: ")
```

or do the tests with numbers:

```
if Shipping == 1
```

Same change regarding Size. Weight look OK.